# Apply two event receivers on the same SPLIST

Tags: event-receivers, itemupdated

As per my requirement, I need to apply TWO event receivers on the same SPLIST,
say **"myLIST1"**.

The first event receiver is already written by my colleague.And I want to apply another set of functionality on the same **"myLIST1"** based on the change of a particular list column.[say `targetresolutiondate`].

If authorized person came to the SPLIST and change the  `targetresolutiondate` column to a `future date` [ greater than today],  I have to fetch this value and navigate it to another document library and manipulate some doc lib items' metadata.

I want to apply **ItemUpdated()**

Comment: So, is your question about whether it's possible to have two event receivers on the same list, or how to implement an event receiver which catches *targetresolutiondate*-column's value and if it's a date in the future, you do <something>?

Comment: my question is, whether its possible to have two event receivers associated with the same SPList and not "HOW TO". whether SharePoint supports this kind of functionality in SSOM

Comment: I believe you'll find this helpful: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129392/manage-multiple-itemupdating-event-receivers-on-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have multiple event receivers on the same list, but why you need to do that? you can add the new event function `Itemupdating` to the current event receiver solution!

**Regarding fetching**

- In case you need to fetch the old value use `Itemupdating` with `properties.ListItem`
- In case you need to fetch the new value use `Itemupdating` with `properties.AfterProperties` or `ItemUpdated` as you like !!

Comment: I prefer itemupdated() eventhandler instead of itemupdating() with synchronous as the value in  elements.xml file.

Comment: Bro, why you prefer that? to handle the synchronous use ItemUpdating  instead of the  ItemUpdated (asynchronous) event in order to access the old value

Comment: :-) in my case, authorized person will access this list and make changes to this field- targetresolutiondate - and set it as Future Date - and i need to compare this Future Date is Greater than Today's date. so i think i can directly access the currentlistitem["targetresolutiondate"] without using properties.afterproperties . I have tested similar functionality with itemupdated event. and it was working as expected.

Comment: Bro, this is not my point now, I talk about old value, in case you don't need to fetch it okay use itemupdated but as told you, you should distinguish between synchronous and asynchronous events. So I answered with additional info where you need to know only the possibility ?!!  finally what's the wrong now in my answer!! :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! :-( I never said your answer is wrong. It was nice to see that , you are offering help and your time to let others learn the intricacies of SP. Thanks Again! :-)

Comment: No Problem, There is no kind of confusion ! and Thank you for your kind words :).